# Selenium scripts failing after windows updates (KB4034674)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-update

I am using Selenium web driver version 3.4.0. After installing recent windows updates (KB4034674), my scripts stopped working. Did anyone faced it and solved this issue?

Please note, I found other article where user faced the issue after installing Windows updates (KB3025390). But solution provided to uninstall the updates. Due to org restrictions, I cannot uninstall the windows updates. But looking forward to the actual issue which caused it and possible solution for it.

Here are the additional details.

```
**Control**
by:By.Id: txtBoxEmail

**Stack Trace:**
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
   at UIAutomation.SeleniumFramework.SeleniumHelper.WaitAndFindElement(By by, Boolean OnlyVisibleElement) in D:\GitRepo\AutomatedTests\Automation_Regression_Selenium\UIAutomation.SeleniumFramework\SeleniumHelper.cs:line 181
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using IE 
Version: 11.483.15063.0 & Update Versions: 11.0.44 (KB4025252)

Also note, we are using C# to prepare the scripts.

Comment: Shot in the dark - There is a change in Site to Zone Assignment List group policy https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034674/windows-10-update-kb4034674. This may effect the security settings for different zones. Does it work for ff or chrome

Comment: Unfortunately, our applications are not compatible with Edge, FF or Chrome. That's why I am trying to find the solution to make it work in IE.